# Como inserir JavaScript com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando inserir JavaScript em um página HTML com JavaScript, após a pagina já ter carregado, mas não consigo  fazer o novo código funcionar , qual o problema?

```
var javascript = "<script> function alerta() { alert('ok'); }</script>";

var button = "<button type='button' onclick='alerta();'>start</button>";

var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', javascript);

body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', button);
```

Obs.: não posso colocar o código dentro do `onclick`!

Comment: O que seria essa tag `<javascript>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma *alternativa* seria criar o script conforme o exemplo abaixo, e no lugar de [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) utilizei o método [`appendChild()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)

```js
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.innerHTML = "function alerta(){alert('ok');}";

var button = "<button type='button' onclick='alerta();'>start</button>";

var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

body.appendChild(script);

body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', button);
```

Comment: Qual a diferença?

Comment: @DenilsonOliveira o método `appendChild` adiciona um elemento no DOM, já o `insertAdjacentHTML`, analisa uma string como html e insere na posição especificada.

Answer (score 0):

A tag `<javascript>` não é procuras, seria `<script>`. Porem quando inseres `</script>` com JavaScript dentro de HTML isso não funciona. Não funciona porque alguns browsers vêm a tag de fecho `</script>` e pensam que é a tag do HTML do script que estás a correr e isso dá erro.

Faz a função com JavaScript "normal", e a inserção do botão como estavas a fazer.

```js
function alerta() { alert('ok'); }
var button = "<button type='button' onclick='alerta();'>start</button>";

var body = document.body;
body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', button);
```

Answer (score -2):

Tente Usar isso para carregar o codigo

```js
<script>
function myFunc(){
    // Aqui vai o codigo que vai rodar antes da pagina ser carregada...
}
window.onload = myFunc;
</script>
```